# Unable to stop/unload non-PnP driver using ServiceManager

Tags: winapi, driver, kmdf

I made a simple non-PnP driver based on the Microsoft sample driver found here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/general/ioctl/kmdf/sys

I think I am doing everything right. My `DriverEntry()` contains:

```
WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&Config, WDF_NO_EVENT_CALLBACK);

Config.DriverInitFlags |= WdfDriverInitNonPnpDriver;

Config.EvtDriverUnload = DriverUnload;

status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject, RegistryPath, &Attributes, &Config, &DriverHandle);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    return status;
}

pInit = WdfControlDeviceInitAllocate(DriverHandle, &SDDL_DEVOBJ_SYS_ALL_ADM_RWX_WORLD_RW_RES_R);

if (pInit == NULL) {
  status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
  return status;
}

return status;
```

I also create the device in the `DriverEntry()` (since it's non-PnP), but the problem persists even without creating the device.

I use ServiceManager to install/start/stop/uninstall the driver.

The install and start work properly. But when I try to stop the driver using `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP`, `ControlService` returns `ERROR_INVALID_SERVICE_CONTROL`. In order to unload the driver, I need to restart the machine.

Is there something I am missing that would prevent the driver from stopping?

Comment: There is a section in the inf that makes the driver unloadable if I recall correctly

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis hmm. I'm not using an INF. I am pointing to the .sys file directly when creating the service.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis - no, are driver can be unload absolute not depend from inf file. *inf* used only on install stage and no more